# How do I check if %Points% < %PCP1% in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have two numeral values, `%Points%`, and `%PCP1%`.
I wish to have something like:

```
IF (%Points% < %PCP1%) ( 
   cls
   echo Not enough money!
   echo Hit enter to return home
   pause
   goto 2
)
ELSE (
   echo Confirm Purchase? Your Points after this purchase will be (%Points% - %PCP1%)
   pause
)
```

It doesn't work. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a description of an actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The less than operator is `LSS` i.e.:

```
IF (%Points% LSS %PCP1%) (
```

Other Operators are:

- EQU: equal to
- NEQ: not equal to
- LSS: less than
- LEQ: less than or equal to
- GTR: greater than
- GEQ: greater than or equal to

Comment: Tried that already, must have typed wrong, it worked for me thanks lol

Comment: @YI: Please note that there should be no brackets around the condition, unless you want them to take part in the comparison. Compare `IF (2 LSS 1) (ECHO OK)` and `IF 2 LSS 1 (ECHO OK)`.